# Logical operators - short (relational) vs long (vector) forms

Tags: r, comparison, vectorization, logical-operators, relational

I am getting a bit confused by the use of the short and long forms of logical operators in R.

If I have the following values

```
A <- FALSE
B <- TRUE
X <- 3
Y <- 2
```

I would like to evaluate  NOT(A) **OR** NOT(B) **AND** X < Y

I expect `FALSE` given the parameters

This is the expression I have found to evaluate this in `R` so it returns `FALSE` as I expect:

```
!A & X < Y || !B & X < Y
```

Can I eliminate the repeated `X < Y` comparison?

Comment: ... You really should use more parentheses to make it clear what you're trying to do.

Comment: @Dason yes, I know now thanks to NPE. Suitably chastised!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do you mean:

```
> (!A || !B) && X < Y
[1] FALSE
```

?

Comment: Ah ha. Exactly, thank you. Parentheses. Damn, I should know better! I will accept as soon as the clock runs down. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

short form gives you a vector.
long form gives you a single value.
compare:

```
   x <- c(TRUE, TRUE, FALSE)
   y <- c(TRUE, FALSE, FALSE)


   X && Y
   X & y

   x || y
   x | y
```

Comment: +1 Really nice example of the way the short and long forms work, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Another possibility:

```
!(A * B) && X < Y
```